# .ASP Web сайт выдает не верную кодировку при ответах

Tags: c#, .net, веб-программирование, кодировка

проблема в следующем - на странице моего сайта (сайт-парсер) есть кнопка, которая отправляет запрос к другому сайту (логин) с помощью `(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.site.ru/login.php");`
В Fillder отслеживаю запрос, всё нормально, приходит ответ с кодировкой windows-1251 `Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251` приносит мне куки я их записываю для последующего общения, тут всё нормально, но дальше когда я отправляю следующий запрос на отображение страницы сайта, в ответ приходит все та же кодировка `Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251` и если я выполняю эти запросы уже с хостинга (залил сайт на хостинг) то при получении ответа я вижу вот такие символы вместо исходного кода запрашиваемой страницы

```
‹í}ms[Ç±ægóWŒ¡Ä -â•ï ­#ë:Þ_n,onÖ¥bÀ!àP”¢«ÿ•k%·²•G±w«öÓ­!B„HâmK^2Ö>Ý3sÎà€)ÉvÝ²Ê–€ƒ™žžžžîžžî>W^ûƒk7~ûáuñËïýJ|øñ/~õî5ŠÄb¿™¹‹½}ãmùÃl4.nÔ²åzÑ.VÊÙR,výýPfâJÁÞ(áŸ_^ëmüóÞõo¡ý#×ÿùãwÿ{:ôß¬»[•Z¾ï¿õÞuóûµÞ¿qýýéPûQ·1-œÎ~ãI'b~™•ò´(Ë
´aÙYQ°íjÄúÝfñv:ô/‘ßŠ\«lT³vqµd…D®R¶­²½{=må×ñ$†~vÑ.Y™ªV®œýý;¿þxòÜ˜ÿE¼ó›l­ýõæ•˜l1q¥nßEË    šÑ´X­äïŠ{¢`×vJ$âñŸ/‹ûQûŽ-îýp|ôîÿ¸žKU{Y\ûàWü:%.Åã33ñø²àßÿé­÷ÞýÕoSâ¶UËgËÙéu«lÝÎNgkÅlIäîÖ–%´Úhpì<à²£AÅã³³çUÜX÷V±vV-%Ê•²u"›*T0Å›ðÂ½?açOüœdÙZÅrìH®R*e«u+…õ•Ÿ–ÕOX•êqiffiifFÔ+¥bž—hku#[€s@˜Ÿ„|¶^°$ˆUk}³\¹ ÙÚz±)Ykv*’XÀˆ>›»µ^«l–ó©ÍZi’˜²žŠÅŠÙu«]ß"Æªmâûzìv2F]/®M‰¸È?AÀšUµ²väÎò@oóv!µôý‰   ôÇœËvÝ@jjácBÙœ’;¼‰M±QÝ|]ÀhºV©ÐØ÷Ë¹’•Åò®VìÂ²î²8¸¶uÇŽdKÅõrJâ¼,  ‘‘¥$¨žÝ´+˜ý³\­H¡Â¼JØŒ·­åj6Ÿ/–×#v¥š(ðX‰|±^-eïbèR%wË;)‰à¡»²‚UOh¤s€µêDêÅß[©El>"¯¦PbÔØ)bŽ¸˜Ãß3‹èÆµ‹¹lIÍ
```

Запрос читаю вот таким вариантом

```
    HttpWebResponse regularResponse = (HttpWebResponse)regularRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(regularResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.Default))
    {
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

        var decodedCyrillic = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(responseFromServer));

        TextBox1.Text += $"\nGetting response from site: {decodedCyrillic}";
    }
    regularResponse.Close();
```

В regularResponse приходит кодировка windows-1251 (koi8-r), далее в переменной decodedCyrillic я пытаюсь получить из windows-1251 кодировку UTF-8 для отображения в текстбоксе полученного исходного кода.
Но если я дебажу сайт из VisualStudio (запуская его на localhost) то всё работает отлично, ответ от запроса на сайт приходит в нормальном читаемом виде с русскими и английскими буквами, не могу понять в чем проблема, помогите, в какую сторону копать?

Comment: Выкиньте строку `var decodedCyrillic ...`. Потому что она _ничего_ не делает.

Comment: `responseFromServer ` - это строка UTF16. **Все** строки в .NET имеют эту кодировку.

Comment: **Никогда** не используйте `Encoding.Default`. Это кодировка на машине, где выполняется код. У вас она, как можно понять,  windows-1251, на хосте - другая. Потому и не работает.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я убрал Default и удалил строчку с decodedCyrillic и вывожу в TextBox просто responseFromServer, но всё равно иероглифы, хоть и другие ��}ms[Ǳ�g�W��� -�_@ZG�u���X�ܬK��C ��(EW�+�Jne+7�b�V�[B���!ږ�d�}�g�9�!   
Что нужно где поменять? на Хостинге? или у меня в коде?

Comment: Нужно указать кодировку. Но не Default. А ту, которая в действительности.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov написал Encoding.GetEncoding(1251) где ранее был Default, но ничего не поменялось - на локальном хосте всё хорошо отображается в ТекстБоксе, а если заливаю на удаленный хост - опять иероглифы...

Comment: сам файл html, где ваш текстбокс находится, вы сохранили в какой кодировке и какой указан в meta тэге язык

Comment: @Konst Файл .aspx содержит <%@ Page Title="" ResponseEncoding="windows-1251" ContentType="text/html; charset=windows-1251" MetaDescription="text/html; charset=windows-1251" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Default.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestAPP.Default1" %>
Сам файл создавался в VisualStudio - "Веб форма с главной страницей".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Проблема решена**

Как подсказали в комментариях, - нужно знать какую кодировку присылает в ответ удаленный сайт, это легко было выяснено с помощью Fiddler, - кодировка "windows-1251" и просто стрим райдеру указываю что читать ответ как `Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251")`:

```
    HttpWebResponse regularResponse = (HttpWebResponse)regularRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(regularResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251")))
    {
        var responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

        Literal1.Text = responseFromServer;
    }
    regularResponse.Close();
```

Но моя проблема была как оказалось не в кодировке...
Когда я с локального хоста отправлял запрос на удаленный сайт пытаясь логиниться, я к запросу присваивал свои заголовки (Headers), я выступал как ХОСТ и естественно это прокатывало, но когда заливал на удаленный хостинг, то уже ЭТОТ хостинг исполнял запрос к сайту и должен подставлять свои заголовки, а я в коде "захардкодил" свои хедерсы, в итоге получалась чепуха. Стоило мне только удалить из кода свои "локальные" заголовки, как удаленный хост спокойно подставил свои, отослал запрос и получил ответ который без проблем отобразился в кодировке "windows-1251".